# Approximate any Lebesgue measurable set with a borel set on $\Bbb R$

Tags: measure-theory

Is this always possible to approximate any Lebesgue measurable set in $\Bbb R$ with a borel set on $\Bbb R$ for measure purpose.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The measure of a set $E$ is the $\sup$ of the measure of compact sets contained in $E$ and the $\inf$ of open sets containing $E$.

Comment: By open sets, you mean countable union of open intervals(a borel set on $\Bbb R$), right??

Comment: A set $A$ is open if for every $x\in A$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset A$.